# Combine lines and calculate their length in SQL Sever 2017 using spatial SQL

Tags: line, sql, merge, sql-server-spatial

I have some geographic line[polyline] data in a table and I wish to merge based on a matching ID number. I then wish to measure the lengths of these combined lines and do all of this via an SQL query.

For example, 5 lines might have the ID, 1 and 7 lines the ID, 2. I want the total length of the ID 1 lines combined and the total length of ID 2 lines combined.

I have looked up how to do this online and whilst I can find examples of using union to merge polygons, I can't find anything for lines. There has to be something though.

The query I wrote was:

```
select STREET_DESCRIPTOR.USRN, DESCRIPTION, STUnion(SW_GEOMETRY) AS COMBINED_SW_GEOMETRY from street_descriptor
join STREET_CROSS_REF on street_descriptor.USRN = STREET_CROSS_REF.USRN
join ESU_GRAPHICS on STREET_CROSS_REF.XUSRN = ESU_GRAPHICS.ESU_ID
group by STREET_DESCRIPTOR.USRN, DESCRIPTION, STUnion(SW_GEOMETRY) 
order by DESCRIPTION
```

This gave the error:

> 'STUnion' is not a recognized built-in function name

Based on that I assumed that STUnion was not the right spatial operator, especially as the documentation I read from Microsoft referred only to polygons when referencing STUnion.

I hope my additional editing of the question is enough to make it no longer off-topic, assuming this is what I needed to do for it to no longer be considered off-topic.

Comment: you can use stunion on any geometry type, as far as I know.  Did you try it?

Comment: you could also sum the lengths with a group by

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I will try stunion again. When I tried it I got errors. As this geographic question has been closed due to being off-topic I can't go any further on it here. Given spatial is geographic, please could someone explain why it is off-topic. G in GIS stands for Geographic. Understanding why it is off-topic will help me ask questions in the right forum in the future.

Comment: When I tried running the query I got the error: **'STUnion' is not a recognized built-in function name.** The query is: `select STREET_DESCRIPTOR.USRN, DESCRIPTION, STUnion(SW_GEOMETRY) AS COMBINED_SW_GEOMETRY from street_descriptor
join STREET_CROSS_REF on street_descriptor.USRN = STREET_CROSS_REF.USRN
join ESU_GRAPHICS on STREET_CROSS_REF.XUSRN = ESU_GRAPHICS.ESU_ID
group by STREET_DESCRIPTOR.USRN, DESCRIPTION, STUnion(SW_GEOMETRY) 
order by DESCRIPTION`

Comment: I'm not super familiar with SQL server so I can't help with the STUnion issue.  Although the problem may be that you don't have the spatial extensions installed.  However, you should not be grouping by stUnion.  Union is an aggregate function - it's aggregating all the geometries for each group.  SO, take it out of your group by.  Check whether you have the spatial extensions intalled.

Comment: `select sum(stLength(geom)), id from table group by id`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I originally didn't have STUnion in the group by clause and still got the same issue. I will try your suggestion jbalk and see what happens. I tried searching on the word line but the Google search engine came back with lots of results relating to lines in code. Polyline, which I guess is probably an old-fashioned term now, didn't bring anything back either.

Comment: I tried running the following but got an error. Doing a search on Google produced no results. It must be said I have been able to insert geometries into a temporary table. `select STREET_DESCRIPTOR.USRN, DESCRIPTION, sum(stLength(SW_GEOMETRY) AS COMBINED_SW_GEOMETRY from street_descriptor
join STREET_CROSS_REF on street_descriptor.USRN = STREET_CROSS_REF.USRN
join ESU_GRAPHICS on STREET_CROSS_REF.XUSRN = ESU_GRAPHICS.ESU_ID
group by STREET_DESCRIPTOR.USRN, DESCRIPTION order by DESCRIPTION`. Error: **'stLength' is not a recognized built-in function name.**

Comment: How do I check if the Spatial extension is installed? I did a search again on Google and didn't get anything useful back in the initial results.

Comment: I checked the SQL server version details and it says Spatial is available in all versions of SQL Sever. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver16#SLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver16#SLS)

Comment: You need to look at how to properly use the functions in SQL server.  My comment was more of an idea than an actual working solution.  I don't use SQL server so I don't know exactly how to structure the queries. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stunion-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stlength-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I think it would be something like `geom.stLength()` or `geom.stUnion()`

Comment: I worked out what my issue was. I was typing the syntax wrong. I was doing `sum(stLength(SW_GEOMETRY))` and not `sum(SW_GEOMETRY.STLength())`. I'm not certain what purpose the brackets at the end of `STLength` serve. Also, I found typing `sum(SW_GEOMETRY.stLength())` also didn't work,. It had to be with `STL` in capitals. Once that was done, the query worked. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Welcome. The brackets mean it is a function.  For future searches try 'linestring' or 'multilinestring' or just 'geometry'.  I don't see polyline used much anymore.  So you could do something like 'length of linestring SQL server' for your search.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. That will be useful. I started drawing maps digitally in 1997, so I'm probably old school with some of my terms.